# Why can I call verfieFormulaire.js but not captureMouvement.js?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to understand why I can't load captureMouvement.js whereas I can load verifieFormulaire.js. Both of them are stored in the same file as my PHP file. I need to use PHP because I really want that page being dynamic.
I'm also running this site on localhost.
Fact : I could call the script when the page was a HTML file.

I've tried to call the script that is already stored on another server. It did not worked. I also tried to move  down to , it did not worked either.
I also tried to call the script using ;?> but this failed too

```
<head> 
    <title>Projet</title>
    <link href="projet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="projet.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src ="https://tp-ssh1.dep-informatique.u-psud.fr/~mpetit4/verifieFormulaire.js"></script>
        <script src ="https://tp-ssh1.dep-informatique.u-psud.fr/~mpetit4/captureMouvement.js"></script>
        <script src ="https://tp-ssh2.dep-informatique.u-psud.fr/~mpetit4/captureMouvement.js"></script>
        <script src ="verifieFormulaire.js"></script>
        <?php echo '<script src ="projetweb/captureMouvement.js"></script>';?>
</head>
```

This should call captureMouvement.js, either from local file or from tp-ssh1.dep-informatique.u-psud.fr.

I opened google chrome, so I could check for javascript console. I got this error message : net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
However, I did not get this error for verifieFormulaire.js

Please, help me.

Comment: Well, that file simply doesn't exist at that address and with that name. Check for typos in the filename and filepath...

Answer (score 0):

If the `.js` files are in the same directory as the HTML page (it doesn't matter if it's a PHP page on your server; it's an HTML page from the browser's perspective), then using no path is correct. So remove the extra `script` tags and the path on them, and there's no need to use PHP to output a static string:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ="https://tp-ssh1.dep-informatique.u-psud.fr/~mpetit4/verifieFormulaire.js"></script>
<script src ="https://tp-ssh1.dep-informatique.u-psud.fr/~mpetit4/captureMouvement.js"></script>
<script src ="https://tp-ssh2.dep-informatique.u-psud.fr/~mpetit4/captureMouvement.js"></script>
<script src ="verifieFormulaire.js"></script>
<?php echo '</script>';?>
```

Those changes give you this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ="captureMouvement.js"></script>
<script src ="verifieFormulaire.js"></script>
```

If that works for `verifieFormulaire.js` but not for `captureMouvement.js`, then there are really only a few possible reasons:

- There's a problem with the permissions on `captureMouvement.js`; make sure they match `verifieFormulaire.js`.
- There's a typo in the name (perhaps you're using a case-sensitive file system and the filename is `capturemouvement.js` or in some other way *subtly* different).
- `captureMouvement.js` *isn't* in the same directory.
- <s>`captureMouvement.js` **is** getting loaded, but failing to parse/run because of a syntax error. Check your web console for errors.</s> *(No, you said you get a 404 for it.)*